# Regex Java phone number

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2,2}9?\\d{4,4}\\d{4,4}");
```

I used the pattern above to match phone number, but numbers like "110123456789" match with pattern. However, the third number is 0 and 9 should be. What is wrong with the pattern?

Phone numbers can have 10 or 11 digits. If the number has 11 digits, the third must be "9".
An example:

11 1234 5678

48 91234 5678

Comment: the phone number depends where you from.
can you post one example or a mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use word boundary `\b`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{2}9?\\d{4}\\d{4}\\b");
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. The question mark tells that the 9 is optional, so remove it if the `9` is required
2. The regex can match part of the string. Use `^` in the beginning and `$` in end of your regex, to match the entire string only. See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2,2}9?\\d{4,4}\\d{4,4}$"); -

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> ^(\d{2})\s?(9?\d{4})\s?(\d{4})$

This will capture your examples and group the digits like

> AA (B)BBBB CCCC